# How to fetch list of documents related to the entity record using CRM APIs?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

Following is the exact scenario in our CRM implementation.

We have created a few custom entities, and enabled "Document Management" for them. Now, we need to get list of all documents (with their full URIs) for each entity record using CRM REST APIs.

I tried to look into the entities, but not sure which entity to query in order to get list of documents (and their URIs) associated with an entity record.

Our documents are getting stored over document library in the SharePoint site.

Could anyone please suggest here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query the [SharePointDocumentLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334644.aspx) entity where the `regardingobjectid` would be the id of the record you want to fetch the document locations for.

Use the `SiteCollectionId` property and query `SharePointSite` entity to get the matching site and construct the url by appending the `AbsoluteUrl` property of the `SharePointSite` entity with the `RelativeUrl` property of the document location entity.